# Brew update fails

Tags: homebrew

Output:

```
○ brew update
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    lapack.rb
    whois.rb
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
Error: Failed to update tap: homebrew/dupes
Already up-to-date.
```

I've tried a bunch of stuff on Stack Overflow and the Brew issues page (https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues#brew-update-complains-about-untracked-working-tree-files) but still no luck. It looks like a slightly different error because it's complaining about homebrew/dupes.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$ cd $(brew --prefix)/Library/Taps/homebrew-dupes/
$ git checkout .
$ git pull --force
$ brew update
```